# Low FPS after JellyBean Upgrade

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, crashes

I bought a Sony Xperia P four months ago. It came with Gingerbread, but was upgradable to ICS. I upgraded it as soon as I got the chance. It was working excellent after the upgrade and didn't give me any chance to complain(except battery consumption).

Yesterday I updated the phone to JellyBean(4.1.2), which was just rolled out. And the phone became laggy like any 3 year old phone. I haven't changed any apps, just updated it. And now after more than 12 hours and 5-8 reboots, it's still laggy. I am getting FPS as low as 5 and it's sometimes crashing the apps too. I've read on some forum, that very few people faced the same problem.

How can I make it run fast again? Or if there's no other way than can I go back to ICS?

Comment: Have you done a factory reset?

Comment: @MichaelHampton A factory reset won't get rid of JellyBean, it will only erase any JellyBean updates: [On system restore, will I lose my software updates?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43892/on-system-restore-will-i-lose-my-software-updates/43896#43896)

Comment: THanks for the try, it's been solved already. I've left an answer for future users too.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I panicked too soon. It was slow because it needs to sync and index all the media files and may be some other sync. I found it out from one of my friends and also experienced it after seeing my media files (video, music etc.) getting added to the list one by one. When I upgraded to ICS there was no media in my device, so it was ready with full performance. And since my phone is overflowing with media now, it was taking some time and running the media sync in the background.

So if you're facing the same problem, just give it a day or two to sync completely, before you try factory reset or downgrade.

PS: I've contacted Sony's customer care and they said that a downgrade can be done at any Sony service center without any charge. Just FYI.