# Updated Android phone with Android N Beta, Will factory reset revert the OS version back?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I updated my Android phone with Android N using Android Beta Program, Now if I factory reset my phone, will it revert the OS version back to the old one?

Comment: No. Factory reset Will [restore to current OS as explained here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43892/131553)

Answer (score 0):

A factory reset will not downgrade your device to Marshmallow. To downgrade to Marshmallow, unenroll your device: https://www.google.com/android/beta.