# Does Family Link work on tablets that are sold with Andriod 6.0 then get software upgrades to 7.0?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat

Google Family Link requires Android 7.0 Nougat on most devices.

Does it work on tablets that are sold with Android 6.0 Marshmallow then get software upgrades to 7.0?

And if so, what is the sequence I need to follow to make this happen?

**Edit**: [Family Link instructions](https://support.google.com/families/answer/7158477?hl=en) require a clean device / factory reset before logging in the child. If I log in, then upgrade to 7.0, then factory reset, will I still be on 7.0 after the reset? Or is there some other way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an app that only works with Android 7.0 will work on all compatible devices regardless of what OS the device first shipped with.

> Children can run Family Link on the following Android devices:
>
> - Nougat 7.0+  Compatible with all devices. ([Source](http://families.google.com/familylink/setup/))

So the sequence to follow would be,

1. Make sure that the device you are purchasing, has an update available for Android 7.0
2. Update the device to latest software from *settings  → about device  → software update*.
3. Download *[Google Family Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.kids.familylink)*, and set it up.

To answer your last question:

> Your phone does not keep an original OS image. Thus, once you update
>   your OS (either by OTA updates or by installing a custom Rom), you
>   will not be able to revert to the older Android version. Doing a
>   factory reset should just reset the phone to a clean slate of the
>   current Android version. ([Source](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/43893/241679))

Comment: Have you tried this? This is not an App install. The Family Link instructions say that for the child's device the steps are to do a Factory Reset on the device, and then sign the child in. will the Factory Reset remove Nougat and reset to Marshmallow?

Comment: @AnonGordon edited my answer to include the fact that a factory reset will not revert you to 6.0| as for trying this, I have installed apps that would not be available on 5.0 but after I updated, they worked. Also, the only reason they want you to do a rest, is to start clean, and not have any apps preinstalled that might get in the way of family link. Otherwise it's a regular app

Comment: @AnonGordon so I'd say, if it's a new device, you don't need to factory reset after upgrade, but you can do it if you want

Comment: Thanks, just ordered an ASUS ZenPad 3S, will let you know how it goes!

Comment: @AnonGordon great! Waiting to hear from you. Let me know if you encounter any trouble

Comment: OK, it worked and installed just fine. I am not quite sure what the order of operations was, however, as the new device was updating the OS and running through the Family Link install at the same time. But it got there in the end (with the ASUS ZenPad 3S, at least).